# How to set up a loop that iterates over possible vector table elements

Tags: c++, vector, discrete-mathematics

The program has to do with arithmetic sequence. I have my program arranged with these constants that are used for indexing

- F = (First term in arithmetic series),
- I = ( increment / common difference between terms),
- L = (Last term in arithmetic series),
- N = (Number of terms in series),
- and T = (Total number by adding all terms in series).

The user should enter 3 of the five 5 characters mentioned above followed by a double value that makes sense for each character.

For example:
If the user inputs:

```
t 3.6 f 1.1 l 1.3
```

or

```
T 3.6 F 1.1 L 1.3
```

The user should receive output of

```
I 0.1 N 3
```

This is because the user has given 3 of 5 options defined as constants

I have defined functions to answer all cases required on user input. I have labeled each function name by first 3 letters being the given and last two letters being the unknown. For the example above, calling `void fltin(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k)` would output `I` and `N`. (2 cases have been exempt and I have created a function to let the user know should those cases arise below)

Another example:
Calling `filnt(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k)` says the user is giving the values of `F`, `I`, and `L`. Output should be `N` and `T`.

My problem: 
I am having trouble at the final steps where given user input (not case sensitive) I can call the correct vector element in TABLE. I want to use a vector of type booleans to also control this.

All help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const unsigned F = 0, I = 1, L = 2, N = 3, T = 4;
bool die(const string & msg);
void filnt(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[T] = v[F];
    for (double i = (v[F] + v[I]); i <= (v[L] + v[I]); i += v[I]) {
        v[T] += i;
    }
    cout << "T:" << v[T] << " ";
    v[N] = (2 * v[T]) / (v[F] + v[L]);
    cout << "N:" << v[N] << endl;
}
void finlt(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[L] = v[F];
    for (double i = 1; i < v[N]; i++) {
        v[L] += v[I];
    }
    cout << "L:" << v[L] << " ";

    v[T] = v[F];
    for (double i = (v[F] + v[I]); i <= (v[L]); i += v[I]) {
        v[T] += i;
    }
    cout << "T:" << v[T] << endl;
}

void fitln(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    bool die("not checking this condition");
}

void flnit(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[I] = (v[L] - v[F]) / (v[N] - 1);
    cout << "I:" << v[I] << " ";
    v[T] = v[F];
    for (double i = (v[F] + v[I]); i <= (v[L] + v[I]); i += v[I]) {
        v[T] += i;
    }
    cout << "T:" << v[T] << endl;
}

void fltin(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[N] = (2 * v[T]) / (v[F] + v[L]);
    cout << "N:" << v[N] << " ";
    v[I] = (v[L] - v[F]) / (v[N] - 1);
    cout << "I:" << v[I] << endl;
}

void ftnil(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[L] = ((2 * v[T]) / v[N]) - v[F];
    cout << "L:" << v[L] << " ";
    v[I] = (v[L] - v[F]) / (v[N] - 1);
    cout << "I:" << v[I] << endl;
}

void iltfn(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    bool die("not checking this condition");
}
void ilnft(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[F] = v[L];
    for (double i = 1; i < v[N]; i++) {
        v[F] -= v[I];
    }
    cout << "F:" << v[F] << " ";
    v[T] = v[F];
    for (double i = (v[F] + v[I]); i <= (v[L]); i += v[I]) {
        v[T] += i;
    }
    cout << "T:" << v[T] << endl;
}

void itnfl(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[F] = ((v[T] * (2 / v[N])) - ((v[N] - 1)*v[I])) / 2;
    cout << "F:" << v[F] << " ";
    v[L] = ((2 * v[T]) / v[N]) - v[F];
    cout << "L:" << v[L] << endl;
}

void lntfi(vector<double> & v, vector<bool> & k) {
    v[F] = ((2 * v[T]) / v[N]) - v[L];
    cout << "F:" << v[F] << " ";
    v[I] = (v[L] - v[F]) / (v[N] - 1);
    cout << "I:" << v[I] << endl;
}

struct FD { 
    double k1; 
    double k2; 
    double k3;
    double uk1;
    double uk2;
    void(*f)(vector<double> &, vector<bool> &); 
};

const vector<FD> TABLE = {
{F,I,L,N,T,filnt},
{F,I,N,L,T,finlt},
{F,L,N,I,T,flnit},
{F,L,T,I,N,fltin},
{F,T,N,I,L,ftnil},
{I,L,N,F,T,ilnft},
{I,T,N,F,L,itnfl},
{L,N,T,F,I,lntfi}
};


int main() {
    vector<double> v(5);
    vector<bool> k = { false, false, false, false, false };
    char cone;
    char ctwo;
    char cthree;
    double one;
    double two;
    double three;
    cin >> cone;
    cin >> one;
    cin >> ctwo;
    cin >> two;
    cin >> cthree;
    cin >> three;
    // for loop I am having trouble constructing 
    /*

    */
}
bool die(const string & msg) {
    cout << "Fatal Error:" << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It seems like the problem is in a couple of lines in main. You dont even call any of the other functions (which are written in a horrible style btw)

Comment: you should use meaningful variable names, it is extremely hard to read that code and make any sense out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a map

```
void assign(std::vector<double>& v, std::vector<bool>& flags, char c, double value)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'F': case 'f': v[F] = value; flags[F] = true; break;
        case 'I': case 'i': v[I] = value; flags[I] = true; break;
        case 'L': case 'l': v[L] = value; flags[L] = true; break;
        case 'N': case 'n': v[N] = value; flags[N] = true; break;
        case 'T': case 't': v[T] = value; flags[T] = true; break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> v(5);
    vector<bool> flags = { false, false, false, false, false };
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
        char c;
        double value;
        std::cin >> c >> value;
        assign(v, flags, c, value);
    }
    const std::map<std::vector<bool>, void(*)(std::vector<double> &)> m = {
        {{true, true, true, false, false}, filnt},
        {{true, true, false, true, false}, finlt},
        {{true, false, true, true, false}, flnit},
        {{true, false, true, false, true}, fltin},
        {{true, false, false, true, true}, ftnil},
        {{false, true, true, true, false}, ilnft},
        {{false, true, false, true, true}, itnfl},
        {{false, false, true, true, true}, lntfi}
    };
    auto it = m.find(flags);
    if (it == m.end()) {
        std::cout << "Fatal Error: not checking this condition\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    it->second(v);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/82Pa7h)

Answer (score 1):

So, to sum up, your problem is that you want to call a function based on three characters entered by the user.

There's no super clever way to do this. In particular you can't somehow work the function names you've chosen into the logic of which function to call. So you should drop the coded function names, and choose names that actually describe what the functions do.

Probably the best way is to have a map from the three letter codes to the function (and maybe to the `vector<bool>`, I didn't really understand that bit).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef void (*function)(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<bool>&);
std::map<std::string, function> table{{"fil", filnt}, {"fin", finlt}, ... };
```

Then you just lookup the function to call based in the three letter code.

```
std::string code{cone, ctwo, cthree}; // make three letter code
table[code](v, k); // call appropriate function
```

Untested code, also you should add some error checking for invalid input.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I had one question while using the map. How exactly would I set the values to the characters being input? I ran it by setting v[F] = 1.1, v[I] = 0.1, and v[L] = 1.3 , and gave me desired output. I am now wondering how I can get values of one, two, and three to be associated with the vector v elements

Comment: @Saul So I'm not completely sure I follow you, but I think you're saying you want to map characters 'F', 'I' , 'L', 'N',  and 'T' to the vector indexes zero to four? If so then that's just another map `std::map<char,int> index{{'F',0}, {'I',1}, {'L',2}, ... };`

Comment: You probably want to lower case and sort `code`, else, you have to put `"FIL", "fil", "liF"`, ... in the map.